# passing xml elements onto a listbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, listbox

Im a newbie to xml as well as WPF. I have an xml file as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Listofattributes>
      <Attribute name="Patient Name" Value="John"/>
      <Attribute name="Sex" Value ="female"/>
</Listofattributes>
```

Im trying to load the values into the listbox in a WPF. Please help me out with how i could do it. Tried reading many articles but i couldn't quite figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XmlDataProvider to refer to a separate file that contains the
data as in:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key=”OrgChartData” Source=”orgchart.xml” XPath=”Sex”/>
```

OR

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key=”regions” XPath=”Regions”>
    <x:XData>
        <Regions xmlns=””>
        <Region RegionName=”East”>
            ...
        </Region>
        <Region RegionName=”Central”>
            ...
        </Region>
        </Regions>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

then determ yor DateTemplate of ListBox.ItemTemplate, which will have Binding like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType=”Region” ItemsSource=”{Binding XPath=*}”>
    <TextBlock Text=”{Binding XPath=@RegionName}” />
</DataTemplate>
```

And your ListBox.ItemsSource should be ="{StaticResource regions}".

If you have separate file, you can write next lines

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key=”regions” Source=”Regions.xml” XPath=”Regions”/>
```

Answer (score 0):

or programmatically:

```
    void form_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(string.Join("", File.ReadAllLines("XMLFile1.xml")));

        foreach (XElement el in xml.Elements())
        {
            ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
            string name = el.Attribute("name").Value;
            string value = el.Attribute("Value").Value;
            item.Content = name + ": " + value;

            ListBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi,Im working on a WPF. So should i put that part of the code in Window_Loaded? Also, when i do the same i get an exception saying data at  root level is invalid. What could i do next?

Comment: Hi,

I tried this but I get an empty listbox, with nothing in it.